# Javascript how to factor in transform-origin when using transform matrix data

Tags: javascript, matrix, css-transforms

I'm trying to find the four corners of a transformed element.
But I currently only have a solution for an element with transform-origin set to 0, 0.

My current steps are:

Get the css transform matrix using

```
 var matrix=getComputedStyle(element).transform.
```

Set the elements transform to 'none'.

```
element.style.transform='none';
```

Get the element's untransformed bounding box

```
var box= element.getBoundingClientRect();
```

Reapply the transformation.

Use the transform matrix to recreate the untransformed rectangle coordinates

```
//2d only matrix example
 var x=(matrix[0]*point[0])+(matrix[2]*point[1])+matrix[4];
 var y=(matrix[1]*point[0])+(matrix[3]*point[1])+matrix[5];
```

You can see a test case here https://jsfiddle.net/pkxzf30t/

**How would I handle elements with a non 0, 0 transform origin?**

Comment: I would like to add I think it's pretty silly browsers go to all the trouble to facilitate complex transforms and then don't do the simple work of making those transform points available to read. They already calculate the transform matrix and give us that, why not the transformed corner vectors?

Comment: Why not just read the `transform-origin` CSS property and account for the offset?

Answer (score 2):

A transform origin property is equivalent (**or works like**, if you prefer it this way) to a translation prior to the transform and the inverse transletion after the transform.

In your case, lets say that you hace a transform-origin: 10px 20px; and a transform: rotate(20deg)

This is equivalent to

- transform: translate(-10px -20px)
- your transform (rotate in this case, but you would use the matrix)
- transform: translate(10px 20px)

You can do this the old way (subtracting 10px from x at the beginning, adding 10px at the end), or calculate the composite matrix and do it in a step